# Reduce the impact of gaussian noise on DTMF decoder

Tags: noise, matlab, fft

I have a Matlab code to decode digits from a given DTMF audio file (wav format). Considering the input signal to be in the form of x(n)+αv(n) where x(n) is the noise-free signal (i.e. the given DTMF audio file), v(n) is white Gaussian noise and α is a constant controlling how much noise is added, following is the block diagram of my code:

[image]

My decoder algorithm is working fairly well but I have been asked to propose ideas to improve my algorithm further. How can I reduce the noise impact? I was thinking to feed my input signal into another block (shown in RED color below) before sending it to decoder.

[image: Block diagram]

But I don't know how to achieve that. Can anyone help on this please?

(Please note that I don't own any of Matlab toolboxes installed on my machine. So any suggestion should be implementable with native Matlab commands)

If the decoding algorithm is needed for answering this question, I have posted a copy of it [here](http://fs2.filegir.com/asghar56/code.html).

Comment: What form does your decoder take?  A bank of Goertzel filters and level detectors?

Comment: @markrages I am afraid I am not following what you mean by that. If you are asking about the decoding method that I have used in my code, I have explained it to Kevin in my comment to answer below. Does that suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is the FFT.

Since the bins of the FFT won't line up perfectly with the DTMF frequencies, some of the tones won't be detected properly as they will be "smeared" across two or more bins (you don't mention sampling rate or the size of your FFT, so I can't tell for sure what bin sizes you will have.)

You can improve the frequency separation by using longer FFT blocks, but then the delay time mounts up.  Longer blocks will help with the noise, too, but if the blocks are too long then short DTMF signals won't be detected (too short.)  You can get around that by using overlap in your blocks.

There's a lot of other things you could do, too.
Since DTMF decoding is an old and well researched field, you could start by seeing how it has been done in the past.
You should also devise a reliable method for determining the reliabilty of your methods.  Look up the term "signal to noise ratio."

Old microprocessor based DTMF decoders used the [Goertzel algorithm,](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/goertzel.html;jsessionid=40781d319a18fdd2beed287502c0?nocookie=true) which is a method for calculating the fourier transform at a specified frequency.  Use a handful of them with the proper frequencies, and see what kind of performance you get.

The older DTMF decoders without microprocessors used a bank of filters, then detected the amplitude at the output of each filter.

At any rate, your first step should be to hit the library (or google) and see what has been done in the past.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your thorough answer. If you look at my code, I measure my algorithm efficiency with calculating SNR (as you correctly pointed out). My sampling rate is 8kHz by the way.

Correct me if I am wrong , you are essentially suggesting to use longer but overlapping blocks to improve the situation. Right?

Also I couldn't work out the rationale behind one of your sentences in 2nd paragraph i.e. "Longer blocks will help with the noise too".

Comment: Longer blocks will average out the noise and result in a clearer peak.  Longer blocks will make the FFT bins narrower, so the frequency detection is more precise.  Longer blocks are also a disadvantage in that they will also require more time to process, and will react slower to changes in input (it will take longer to detect a DTMF code) and make it hard/impossible to detect short DTMF codes.

Answer (score 2):

One way to reduce the effect of noise is to reduce the bandwidth, either pre-detection or by averaging after detection.

The module you have drawn is before detection so it would be by adding a narrow band filter at each of the 7 DTMF tones then recombining into a single signal of the DTMF decoder, or giving each tone its own decoder.

The width of filter would depend upon how long the tones are present in the original signal.

There may be some parameter of the DTMF decoder than can be adjusted to optimize it to match the length of the incoming signal.  At some point you will not be able to improve the response though.

You may also be able to put averaging after the DTMF decoder to require that a signal be present for a defined time before it is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Couple of things I would like to ask you for further explanation if you don't mind. 
My decoding idea is as such that my code reads the `wav`file using `audioread`. Then I add the gaussian noise to it to replicate what may happen in  reality. I then split the result vector into blocks of 1600 samples and then process them through i.e. compare the maximum peaks in `fft` magnitudes with DTMF table to determine the digits. Now I can't quite understand how your `filter` idea matches with my implementation. Can you please elaborate it for me?

Comment: Also the `averaging` idea was what I initially suggested to my supervisor but here is his answer: "You can’t apply synchronous averaging in this case, because you don’t know the precise time-alignment of the signals. The sync. averaging applies when, for example, you create a signal and measure the received signal. You have no guarantee of when the tone starts." That's why I thought I am off-track with `averaging` idea. Does the above quote make sense to you?